# ABI for Etherscan verification

Tags: contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, abi, verify

How I can get ABI in multiple contract code? if the code is [here](https://gist.github.com/CareFully220/34ac6ae67c514ab2c37ce986d83c5d4d):

Token address is: `0x4960a0Db832c3Bb503F3Da59a274D9385e0Ade5A`

Crowdsale contract: `0x7a76d1A86a8b801865eC9134552904366b327A45`

I tried to generate with values inside here: function `MainCrowdsale(uint256 _saleLengthInMinutes, uint256 _rate, uint256 _goal, uint256 _cap, address _wallet)`

Values should be: `33120; 1200; 50; 5000;` `0x4960a0Db832c3Bb503F3Da59a274D9385e0Ade5A` Am I correct?

Do I need to create more values or is there problem because there's mintable token and token value can't be set until crowdsale ends?

Comment: But How I can get encoded ABI from this code?

Comment: values are not used in getting method signature, only method definition is used

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://remix.ethereum.org/

Copy and paste the code. Click on Details and look for the Interface section. Click on Copy button and paste your ABI wherever you like. Here's what I got when I did this:

`[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]`

Sorry - I'm short on time, so I'm not sure this is right (it looks too short), but this should give you a direction.